# Error retrieving training data Asset is not found on Watson studio

Tags: annotations, ibm-watson, visual-recognition, labelimg

What might be the reason from the above error on Watson Studio(Visual Recognition Custom Model).

Anytime I am labelling my images for training a custom model on the watson studio, the labelling stops at a point and this results to a blank page. 
**How can I resolve this issue this and what might be the cause** ..?

Answer (score 0):

For issues specific to your assets or account, which it sounds like this is, it's best to open a support request at https://cloud.ibm.com/unifiedsupport/supportcenter

Comment: I have created an issue on the support center and no one has responded to it